# PHP Curl HTTP CODE 302 redirect not working and getting redirect_url

Tags: php, curl

I have a problem with a CURL call with the following domain: http://www.credit-suisse.com we use this in a scraper function to get some DOM elements (OG data) like title, description, image, etc, nothing special really.

I get back the following response from curl_getinfo and after that it doesn't do anything, it doesn't fetch any content.

```
Array ( [url] => https://www.credit-suisse.com/ [content_type] => text/plain [http_code] => 302 [header_size] => 244 [request_size] => 60 [filetime] => -1 [ssl_verify_result] => 0 [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] => 0.873153 [namelookup_time] => 3.5E-5 [connect_time] => 0.169979 [pretransfer_time] => 0.687172 [size_upload] => 0 [size_download] => 0 [speed_download] => 0 [speed_upload] => 0 [download_content_length] => -1 [upload_content_length] => 0 [starttransfer_time] => 0.87313 [redirect_time] => 0 [redirect_url] => https://www.credit-suisse.com/index.html?vanityUrl=%2F [primary_ip] => 198.240.216.35 [certinfo] => Array ( ) [primary_port] => 443 [local_ip] => 72.47.244.19 [local_port] => 37662 )
```

It does not get or follow the REDIRECT_URL, curl error info also does not show any errors.

We have the following code:

```
function curl_exec_follow(/*resource*/ $ch, /*int*/ &$maxredirect = null) { 
$mr = $maxredirect === null ? 5 : intval($maxredirect); 
if (ini_get('open_basedir') == '' && ini_get('safe_mode' == 'Off')) { 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, $mr > 0); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, $mr); 
} else { 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false); 
    if ($mr > 0) { 
        $newurl = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL); 

        $rch = curl_copy_handle($ch); 
        curl_setopt($rch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true); 
        curl_setopt($rch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true); 
        curl_setopt($rch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, false); 
        curl_setopt($rch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
        do { 
            curl_setopt($rch, CURLOPT_URL, $newurl); 

            $header = curl_exec($rch); 
            if (curl_errno($rch)) { 
                $code = 0; 
            } else { 
                $code = curl_getinfo($rch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); 
                if ($code == 301 || $code == 302 || $code == 303) { 
                    preg_match('/Location:(.*?)\n/', $header, $matches); 
                    $newurl = trim(array_pop($matches)); 
                } else { 
                    $code = 0; 
                } 
            } 
        } while ($code && --$mr); 
        curl_close($rch); 
        if (!$mr) { 
            if ($maxredirect === null) { 
                trigger_error('Too many redirects. When following redirects, libcurl hit the maximum amount.', E_USER_WARNING); 
            } else { 
                $maxredirect = 0; 
            } 
            return false; 
        } 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $newurl); 
    } 
} 
return curl_exec($ch); 
} 

function get_url($url) {

$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 120;

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$data = curl_exec_follow($ch);
print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));

return $data;

curl_close($ch);

if(curl_errno($ch))
{
echo 'error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
}
```

Note:: We can't use CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION because of safemode and openbasedir set.

Is there any way to make curl follow the redirect_url, or maybe someone has a clever solution. Would also like to know how i can catch this issue? So if there is no solution i can print out a error message or return something.

Thank you very much.